# Determine if onpaste event was triggered by keyboard or mouse click

Tags: javascript, events, paste

Is there a way to determine whether the Element.onpaste event was triggered by ctrl/cmnd+v or by mouse right click and "paste" selection from the contextual menu?

Comment: That is supposed to be trivial information, why would you need it?

Comment: Because something is happening on keyup event that gets picked up on paste when done via keyboard but doesn't when you paste via mouse clicks. So I need to determine if it was a mouse click and do stuff then.

Comment: You could detect `e.ctrlKey`, if `false` --> paste comes from (context)menu, otherwise paste comes from keyboard. Though this detection will fail, if you press CTRL and select Paste from context menu...

Comment: @Teemu I don't have access to Windows at the moment, but doesn't seem to work for Mac's Command key (chrome). http://jsfiddle.net/dBAa7/

Comment: I'm gone a different route to avoid needing this as it doesn't seem to be possible outside of the box.